# Redactor this.insert.html() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

I'm using [Redactor II](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) as text editor for a CMS I'm developing, the problem is that a little function isn't working and I don't know why, because everything was installed fine and was working on previous website that I used Redactor.

Even the Table plugin, and line button aren not working. This an example of a plugin I'm making.

```
var grid_items = {};
$.Redactor.prototype.grids = function()
{
    return {
        init: function()
        {
            grid_items.grid01 = { title: '20-80', func: this.grids.insertGrid };
            grid_items.grid02 = { title: '20-20-60', func: this.grids.insertGrid };
            var button = this.button.add('grids', '<i class="fa fa-table"></i>');
            this.button.addDropdown(button, grid_items);
            $redactor = this;
        },
        insertGrid: function(button)
        {
            var grid = grid_items[button].title;
            var grids = grid.split('-');
            var html = '';
            $.each(grids, function(){
                html += '<p>123</p>';
            });
            this.insert.html(html);
        }
    };
};
```

The problem is on the last line, `this.insert.html()` will not work, but `this.insert.set()` works. They do different things as stated in the api documentation.

This is not my plugin problem, since the official plugins that use this, are not working too...

Anyone faced this before ? What am I missing here?